# return a promise around anound promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Given somePromise(param

I want to create another promise that will do some processing and then resolve/reject based on the result of somePromise:

```
function wrapPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // some processing
        somePromise(someParam).then(function() { resolve(); },  function(err) { reject(err); });
    });
}
```

is this the right way to do this or is there a shorter syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for sounds like `I will make a promise to make a promise. And, therefore, the first promise should fail if the second fails.`

Forget about programming for a second: It will just complicate things if you say, *I will make a promise to make a promise that I will not eat icecream.* No, You just make a promise that you won't eat icecream.

Think about re-designing your code such that you may make it simpler, saying, *I will make a promise (A) which can be resolved or rejected. I will make another separate promise (B) which can be resolved or rejected independent of A.*

Or just use one promise but divide code in separate 'then' chains, e.g.

```
promise.then(function(result) {  // First 'then'
  console.log(result);           // Resolve case
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);              // Reject case
}).then(function(val) {          // Second 'then'
  console.log(val);              // Resolve case
});
```

For better understanding I will highly recommend reading: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the extra promise. Just do your processing and then return the promise.

```
function wrapPromise() {
    // some processing
    return somePromise(someParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it reverse of what you have. Get the value first, then do your processing and return a Promise (assuming it's async).

```
var myPromise = somePromise(someParm)
    .then(function (retVal) {
        return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // Some processing with retVal e.g.
            if (retVal > 5) {
                resolve(retVal);
            } else {
                reject('value less than 5');
            }
        })
    })
    // Then you can do other stuff
    .then(function (val) {
        console.log('this value is greater than 5', val);
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
        console.log(reason); // 'value is less than 5'
    });
```